# What languages were used for coding 50 years ago?

Tags: discussion, survey-2019

What were programmers coding 50 years ago? Are they still actively programming and using Stack Overflow?

[image: Graph for the Years Coding Professionally question in the Stack Overflow survey shows that 0.1% of respondents have been coding for 50 years or more.]

Comment: You don't want to know

Comment: Probably COBOL.  There's so much legacy COBOL in the world.

Comment: I started on Apple ][e, at the tender old age of 10.  I look back, and remember actually writing out code *on paper*.  And getting magazines full of, "programs" you had to type in manually.  And all this existed when I started.

Comment: [tag:cobol] on [tag:mainframe]

Comment: Not quite 50 years, but 48 years ago I was a Physics undergrad using Fortran IV for computational physics problems. A bit later lots of IBM mainframe assembler.

Comment: I know my grandfather currently codes in QuickBasic, which apparently can run on Android.

Comment: [The first commercially available language was FORTRAN (FORmula TRANslation); developed in 1956](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_programming_languages).  That was sixty-three years ago, and it is still in use today.  C is 47 years old and is currently ranked #2 on the TIOBE index.

Comment: What? Things existed before I was alive? The devil you say!

Comment: We even have questions about code which [could be](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16960949/3157076) 50 years old.

Comment: I think the question of language is less interesting than what code editor they used.

Comment: This is an interesting question, you may find several more retro questions on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [What programming languages were used to go to the moon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739561/what-programming-languages-were-used-to-go-to-the-moon) Also [see it on GitHub](https://qz.com/726338/the-code-that-took-america-to-the-moon-was-just-published-to-github-and-its-like-a-1960s-time-capsule/) [here](https://github.com/chrislgarry/Apollo-11).

Comment: @Cody Gray they had [tech support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSSmNUl9Snw) too!

Comment: In addition to Assembler, Fortran and Cobol there also was RPG. Never had to touch the latter, TG. Cobol was a lot better than folks today think, esp. once it got PERFORM, ie procedural syntax.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu: you didn't need an editor with card decks.  You punched a new card and inserted it into the right place in the deck.  Yes, I used them (not for long, I'm glad to say, but I used punched cards) and they were a pain except as a source of paper for writing notes on.

Comment: @TaW - RPG was also a lot better than folks today think. And like Fortran and Cobol, it has continued to evolve.

Comment: [Forth had its 50 years birthday last year](http://www.hidecs.co.uk/EF2018.html). Refactoring was born then (but not by that name) - it was (partly) a necessity. [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) [tag here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forth).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler *you didn't need an editor with card decks* BUT if you dropped the deck you needed a sorter (or a great deal of patience) :) and hence why chars 72-80 tend to be for the line number, so they can be sorted. Did my fair share of punched cards and that was mid 80's.

Comment: [Interview with Chuck Moore at the conference that celebrated the birthday of Forth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SX3kXbLmwn4) (2018). [*Retrocomputing* post](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25506/did-forths-inventor-charles-moore-really-write-a-cad-program-in-only-5-lines-of).

Answer (score 42):

During the 1960's, the three most popular languages were assembly, Cobol, and Fortran. For IBM mainframes, the programming interface for database file access were implemented as macros in assembly, so in some environments, programs ended up as a mix of assembly and Cobol, and due to legacy issues (why convert already working code?), continue to still exist today.

Going further back in history to the days of "unit record equipment", plug boards were used for "programming".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plugboard

Early vacuum tube computers were programmed in the equivalent of machine language.

Getting back to the 1960's, other languages existed, but weren't as popular. APL is an interactive mathematical language and still available today. RPG II was sort of a replacement for plug board programming. Other languages include Algol, Basic, PL/1, ... .

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say RPG II was a replacement for plug board programming. It is fair to call it a "punch card" language, but of course almost all programming was done on punch cards in that era.

Comment: @JohnY - one thing RPG II shares in common with plug boards is the unit record type [declarative_programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) used to define links between input fields with formatted output fields or accumulators, where the order of operations is not defined and in theory, could be performed in parallel.

Comment: "_why convert already working code?_" for readability, for modern code analysis, for new architectures, for all the reasons that we have newer programming languages, and for many other reasons (like working with a language known by younger generations).

Comment: @Cœur - perhaps I should have stated why convert thousands of lines of already working code in business critical environments (like banks). The risk factor of something going wrong is too high for most shops to consider conversion, and IBM mainframes are for the most part, backwards compatible to the days of the 360, such as 24 bit mode in [z/Os](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z/OS).

Comment: In the modern descendant of unit-record programming, namely shell pipelines, the order of operations is indeed performed in parallel.

Answer (score 22):

If you can find a copy of the book [History of Programming Languages](https://smile.amazon.com/History-Programming-Languages-Acm-Monograph/dp/0127450408), edited by R L Wexelblat, published in 1981, you'd find sessions on:

- FORTRAN
- Algol
- LISP
- COBOL
- APT
- JOVIAL
- GPSS
- Simula
- JOSS
- BASIC
- PL/I
- SNOBOL
- APL

The requirements for the languages chosen were that the "languages (1) were created and in use by 1967; (2) remain in use in 1977; and (3) have had considerable influence on the field of computing".

There were many, many other languages in use around then.  A lot of code was also written in assembler — or macro assembler.

There was a second conference later, published as [History of Programming Languages II](https://smile.amazon.com/History-Programming-Languages-Thomas-Bergin/dp/0201895021), edited by T J Bergin and R G Gibson, published 1996.  That covers a lot of later, more familiar languages, including:

- Algol 68
- Pascal
- Monitors and Concurrent Pascal
- Ada
- Lisp (again)
- Prolog
- Discrete Event Simulation Languages
- FORMAC
- CLU
- Smalltalk
- Icon
- Forth
- C
- C++

Java and JavaScript had not been around long enough to warrant consideration.  Scripting languages like Perl, Python, Ruby, Tcl/Tk, were not included either.

If HOPL III were held in 2020, which languages would it cover, I wonder?

Comment: I started with SNOBOL in 1980 ... enjoying this trip down memory lane.

Comment: You left out [the best one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL)!

Comment: @JackBashford: That was deliberate: INTERCAL was created in 1972 — it isn't (yet) valid for languages in use 50 years ago.

Answer (score 16):

I started programming in 1967 in Fortran. A friend of my father had a Honeywell 200 at his factory, invited me down one Saturday, and got me started with punch cards and Fortran. He then gave me a job that summer. Their professionals were using Cobol, so I managed to learn that, along with a little assembler. (The "200" was basically an IBM 1401 clone.)

In the fall I started college at Dartmouth. Soon as my parents had left, I marched into the computer center and asked the woman in charge how I could get permission to use the computer. She pointed to the terminal room (Model 35 teletypes) and said, "Take any empty terminal. Your student ID is your login."

When I asked HOW to use it, she handed me a thin green book titled, "Dartmouth BASIC." I still treasure it.

Long story short, Dartmouth Time-Sharing, which was almost entirely written by undergraduates led by Professors Kemeny and Kurtz, made BASIC, and computing, ubiquitous on campus. Classes from physics and engineering (obviously) to sociology used it. Not to mention various primitive text-oriented games. It was free, and there were terminals all around the campus.

I learned assembly for the GE 635 from Professor Kemeny, joined the system staff, and learned enough by the time I graduated to keep learning.

If you're at all interested in the history of BASIC and Time-sharing, they made this movie for the 50th anniversary in 2014:

[Beginning of BASIC](https://youtu.be/gxo9LVIgOiI)

[History](https://youtu.be/WYPNjSoDrqw)

Several of the programmers in the video had returned to teach by the time I arrived.

Answer (score 10):

I've only been programming for 40 years, not 50.

I started in the late 70s (as an 8 year old) with BASIC on the Apple ][, Atari 8-bit, [ZX-81](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX81) (aka Timex/Sinclair 1000), and [Ohio Scientific Challenger 4P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohio_Scientific). I taught myself Zilog Z80 and 6502 assembly language. The Atari 8 bit systems had a really nice macro assembler and debugger called [Mac/65](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC/65). I then got into [Action!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action!_(programming_language)) on the Atari 8-bit. I wrote myself a bitmap font editor and a disk sector editor using it. I also dabbled in [Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)).

I then graduated to Pascal and C on the Atari ST in the mid-80s. And then took a university class on FORTRAN 77. I then started doing C and C++ on Unix systems (mid to late 80s). Around that time I also learned Scheme and Lisp.

I wrote my own B-Tree indexing system and AVL tree implementation (complete with the rarely described (in fact, I have never seen it described, figuring out how to do it forced me to a deeper understanding of binary trees) and annoying to implement delete operation) in C for MS-DOS for a small employer paying me $6/hr in 1988-9. I wrote it as part of converting their accounting and inventory systems to C and C++ from GW-Basic.

We didn't have anything like StackOverflow at the time. Usenet was sometimes useful, but mostly I relied on reference manuals. Good ones were hard to come by and treasured when you found them. Donald Knuth's *Searching and Sorting* was a treasure. The K&R manual for C was also a bible to live by. The various technical manuals for the hardware I used (such as [*Mapping the Atari*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_the_Atari)) were vital. So were *The Design and Evolution of the C++ Programming Language* and the *ARM* (aka *Annotated C++ Reference Manual*). [*Oh! Pascal*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393954455) was how I learned Pascal.

So that's a bit of what programming was like way back then.

BTW, I still used version control. RCS. Mercurial is MUCH better. Not so sure about git being an improvement though.

Lastly, I'll also say that of all the programming languages you'll hardly ever use, by far the most valuable to learn is Lisp. Ideas from Lisp are still inspiring new programming languages to this day.

Comment: (I'd add Forth and Smalltalk to the "most valuable to learn". Among the oldest reasonable languages, still my favorites, and I regret Java won the language war in the early 90s. If Lisp hadn't fragmented and Smalltalk had had the same VM love Java has gotten...)

Answer (score 9):

Computer programming started to assume the shape of OOP before 50 years. [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk), the first-ever OOP language which inspired the OOP models of Java and Object Pascal emerged around this time.

Wikipedia articulates the contributions made by the forerunners of this historical trend as such:

> Smalltalk was the product of research led by Alan Kay at Xerox Palo
>   Alto Research Center (PARC); Alan Kay designed most of the early
>   Smalltalk versions, Adele Goldberg wrote most of the documentation,
>   and Dan Ingalls implemented most of the early versions. The first
>   version, termed Smalltalk-71, was created by Kay in a few mornings on
>   a bet that a programming language based on the idea of message passing
>   inspired by Simula could be implemented in "a page of code".[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kay) A
>   later variant used for research work is now termed Smalltalk-72 and
>   influenced the development of the Actor model. Its syntax and
>   execution model were very different from modern Smalltalk variants.

[Alan Kay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kay)

[Adele Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_Goldberg_(computer_scientist))

[Dan Ingalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Ingalls)

Comment: 50 years ago was 1969.  So if Smalltalk was the first, then it started assuming that shape less than 50 years ago.  Or not?

Comment: Smalltalk was the result. The research and programming led to that  happened more than 50 years ago.

Comment: maybe you have a look to [Simula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) which is a bit older.

Comment: Yes. However Simula is considered incomplete since its objects were abstract data types than  autonomous entities as we know by the name of objects today.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu: I remember that Alan Kay said in a talk that the oldest code he could find that implements something we would today call "object-oriented" was from 1953.

Answer (score 9):

My first encounter with a computer was a
[bus](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Burnley,_Colne_%26_Nelson_Joint_Board_bus_36,_1953_Leyland_PS2_East_Lancashire_Coachbuilders_BHG_755.jpg)
which came from Manchester University in my last year at secondary school, 1971,
at Nelson Grammar School. We were given a guided tour as part of our Science lessons.

We were shown round the bus which was filled with what looked like metal filing cabinets on each side and a lot of whirring noises.
It was hot. We were told the computer had 4k (I think) of [Mercury Delay Line storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_line_memory#Mercury_delay_lines).

The computer was doing simple calculations such as 2+2=4 and printing them out on a teletype. During the demonstration the computer
developed a fault and stopped and the chap giving the talk looked at the error message and then thought for a moment. I got the impression
that he was working out which part of the computer had failed. Then he pointed to one of the filing cabinets towards the front
and to the right. "Hmmm that should be about there" he said. He walked over to it and kicked it with his foot. The computer
sprang back into life!

My first encounter with coding was in FORTRAN IV on an
[ICL 1906A](http://www.chilton-computing.org.uk/acl/technology/1906a/p005.htm) with the
[George III](http://www.chilton-computing.org.uk/acl/technology/1906a/p002.htm)
operating system at Nottingham University
the same year 1971. It was the norm to use Roman numerals for the George III operating system in the same way as
[FORTRAN IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#FORTRAN_IV).

When I went to Nottingham University, to do Chemistry and Physics, we wrote programs
on [a FORTRAN coding form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#/media/File:FortranCodingForm.png) which is squared paper similar to graph paper to
start with and then transferred the program to [punched cards](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/FortranCardPROJ039.agr.jpg)
and submitted the deck to the computer for an overnight batch run.

The data for the program was entered in the same way, on punched cards. These were submitted for an
overnight batch run. The output was on music ruled computer paper
which we got the next day. What was really frustrating was a compile error which needed to be corrected
and re-submitted the next day - we only got one run per night.