# Take the 2021 Developer Survey

Tags: discussion, survey-2021

Our 2021 Developer Survey opened today! Whether an active member of the Stack Overflow community or not, we encourage everyone who codes to participate and make their voice heard. The survey will be open until June 15 and should only take about 10 minutes to complete (that's ten minutes shorter than last year).

[Take the survey](https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_7arimtzVFf8ipfM)

As happened in previous years, any user who completes the survey in its entirety will earn the Census badge. You will have the option to get the badge on Stack Overflow, or on a different technical site in the Stack Exchange network.

Anonymized survey results will be available publicly under the Open Database License. You'll be able to download and analyze the dataset later this year. Certain survey answers are treated as personally identifiable information, and therefore excluded from the anonymized results. These questions are highlighted in the survey with a note saying, "This information will be kept private."

Thanks in advance for your time and additionally thank you to everyone who gave us feedback on [our listed technologies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407253/review-our-languages-and-platforms-for-dev-survey-2021) for this year's version!

If you use security or ad-blocking plugins, you may see error messages. Our third-party software provider, Qualtrics, does not work well with certain ad blockers and security software. To avoid error messages that prevent you from taking the survey, please try specifically unblocking Qualtrics in your plugin or pausing the plugin while you take the survey. Additionally, as a reminder, Qualtrics blocks certain countries from accessing their site and data: Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Syria, and the Crimea region of Ukraine (including Sevastopol). In addition, some users in China may have issues due to restrictions imposed by local internet service providers.

If there are any bugs, questions, or concerns, we encourage you to add them to this post as answers.

Thank you!!

Comment: @KevinB Not in my experience. I didn't answer a few questions and I still got the census badge.

Comment: @KevinB The [badge description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census) also explicitly states that "your responses are anonymous"; if they're truly confidential, the badge award system has no idea whether you answered anything or not.

Comment: I'm disappointed by how it feels like over half the questions were demographics of some type, and by how there was no community input on the questions to make it at least a little less boring in the "real" (read: not demographics) part.

Comment: Again, great survey! Looking forward to the results. One thought on [the 'transgender' question](https://i.imgur.com/mwQb9Zo.png), is 'Queer` really a necessary option next to 'Gay/Lesbian' and 'Prefer to self-descibe'? [GayCenter.org (and others) says](https://gaycenter.org/about/lgbtq/#queer): *Once considered a pejorative term, queer has been reclaimed by some LGBTQ people to describe themselves; however, it is not a universally accepted term even within the LGBTQ community.* Not sure this is the right choice of words.

Comment: @0stone0 Why would it not be a necessary option? The very source you linked just describes it as "Not exclusively heterosexual", that's not covered by Gay/Lesbian, and why should it need to be self-described when there's already a word for it?

Comment: Slightly disappointed that I was unable to express my dissatisfaction with certain technologies this year.

Comment: @Joe don't be disappointed, you can downvote all posts with that technology for the whole year....

Comment: @rene I'm pretty sure if I started serial down voting every post in [hatedtech] I'd quickly get smacked by an anti-abuse script.  And rightly so, my hatred of it doesn't make all questions asked in it bad.  OTOH If someone with pointy hair came to me and was suggesting we switch our current stack out for hatedtech, being able to point out that it was hatevoted by 3:1 on the dev survey SO would be more likely to carry weight than just a simple "ugh hatedtech sucks".

Comment: I think the most loved / most hated tech thing is a bit shallow and unfair, probably a better way to structure it would be "would you choose to use this tech for future projects, given the choice?". E.g., I don't love everything about C++ but I want to keep working with it because it's the best option I have for what I do. However there are a few things that are way behind their competition or have such major issues that they provide little to no value.

Comment: I did the test about nine hours ago and haven't received the badge - how long does it take on average?

Comment: @J.M.Arnold [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) ....

Comment: Apparently it's a known fact that the survey banner will not display if you are a Teams member. I see a deleted answer, but other than that, no indication here that the problem is known or acknowledged.

Comment: Just a remark: "You will have the option to get the badge on Stack Overflow" - well, there was no such option.

Comment: Is there a way to vote for new questions on the survey for next year?

Comment: Survey was okay. The demographics questions are still a bit invasive but they gave them less focus than last year.

Comment: Re *"...will earn the Census badge"*: Shouldn't that be *"...can earn the Census badge"* (as it is an option at the very end)?

Comment: @MarekLegris Typically there is a Meta post a few months beforehand asking 'what kind of questions do you want to see on the next dev survey', so yes there will be an opportunity; if they don't post one of those questions, you could create one yourself.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401807

Comment: I just looked at the [Octoverse survey](https://octoverse.github.com/), which is a bit similar to this survey and now I don't feel like a programmer anymore. All these questions about best practices and at my place we are only following a very small part of them. Maybe I should downgrade myself to technology enthusiast...

Comment: I think this was the first year when the survey didn't assume that I live in the US or that the rest of the world isn't just like USA. So that's a major improvement.

Comment: @CrisLuengo comments _are_ meant for clarification, and constructive discussion. But if you have something important to say, an answer is the way to go.

Comment: I think it was unclear that if you still work with a certain tech you have to select both boxes. Yes, it is in the text, but the question felt so obvious after the first sentence that I started on the boxes. It wasn't for the 3th similar question that I noticed I had to check both and return to the previous questions. I wouldnt be suprised if more people did this wrong and it could give very strange results.

Comment: One thing that I find curious is that in Brazil we don't have a "Latin" race; this is a way other countries usually classify Latin American people.

Comment: I'm not sure why would you need a survey while at the end you will be skewing the published result based on data you have extracted to your desire, to show that some language or framework, is more popular because it had more questions comparing to past year!

Comment: @Gabriel You can always create a post asking if it got corrected. It'd give other people a place to answer you.

Comment: The developer survey did not have any questions around remote work, which was the new normal for most of the developers last year.
I was expecting questions like this
What is your preference - remote/office
Tools used by you to collaborate
etc...

Comment: @SKrishna I hadn’t thought about that, but that’s a really good point. Not including questions on that was a big miss this year.

Comment: I'm just wondering who is this @stephanie who just have only 101 reputations.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal As you can see in [her bio](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10624141/stephanie?tab=profile), she's a Program Manager at Stack Overflow. That means she's a staff member who is apparently involved with the survey, regardless of reputation. (Not sure why she doesn't have the orange "Staff" badge, though. Perhaps you should ask about that internally, Stephanie?)

Comment: I am very *disappointed* with this year's survey. The survey was too short & failed to capture a lot many relevant questions. Why was it kept too short? Were you fearful that the `tick tock` generation has lost the patience to make it to the end? We as `software engineers` & `developers` have far more patience. 

If someone has decided to commit for a survey, their time should have been respected by asking the right questions which had a holistic coverage. Where's crypto/blockchain? Where's new programming languages? Where's new web frameworks? Webassembly? `vim v/s emacs?` `tab v/s spaces?`

Comment: We're sorry, but the 2019 Developer Survey is now closed. See you next year, when we launch the 2020 Developer Survey.

Comment: Just a heads up that clicking the survey link now brings you to [a page that reads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPlVG.png): "We're sorry, but the 20**19** Developer Survey is now closed. See you next year, when we launch the 20**20** Developer Survey."

Answer (score 149):

It is a nice survey. It felt shorter than previous years.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I was surprised by this question though:

[image: How did you learn to code? Has six options for people, schools, and online sources and a seventh option for 'Other'.]

Did y'all forget that books exist? Books and magazines (those things printed on dead trees) were the only way that self-taught coders could learn before the internet.

Comment: or learning by doing, working, etc, not every aspect of "learning" is about finding some resource online to copy paste from.

Comment: I am so glad that you enjoyed the survey! This was a new addition to the survey this year so we appreciate the feedback for the options!

Comment: I felt old when I had to check "Other => books" :D

Comment: I agree that books/physical media deserve their own option. Much like many people my age, I started learning online, but lately I've been reading more books. They are great resources.

Comment: I read the ZX Spectrum Instruction Manual. Where I learned Basic. Imagine that ... a "computer" came with an instruction manual which taught how to program.

Comment: As well as books, there's also "type stuff in and see what happens" and "read the built-in manual"

Comment: We've updated the form to include Books / Physical media as an option. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Catija When I was learning to program my MSX home computer there was a radio show that would on occasion share a program. In audio form for you to record on cassette and the computer then to load from the cassette. 15 minutes of screeching noises! Wireless software transmission in the 1980s was a very different concept :-D I don’t suppose “Traditional media” would be an option?

Comment: @MartijnPieters ha! I still make those sounds. MSX 1 or 2?

Comment: I definitely taught myself BASIC as a child from numerous library books.

Comment: There's also "read a lot of source code" and "read the online documentation".  I did that a ton with Java while in university.

Comment: Oddly, "status completed" means there is now Books, but I didn't learn from books at all, so I still had to put magazines as a separate "Other" entry.

Comment: Lol..... yeah.... I put a comment in about books in the other.

Comment: Time and time again, I have to refrain from commenting *"Maybe you should try reading a book?"* on questions where the asker is unable to solve their problem *"even after watching many YouTube videos"*. I suspect that in 10 years, I'll be recommending people to watch a YouTube video if they can't find the answer on TikTok or Instagram.

Comment: Yes, perhaps the usability testing of the survey before release should include a more diverse demographics [than generation Z](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZps0fR5TE4&t=27s).

Comment: One could just remove "online" from the options texts, then other resources would be just fine. Does it matter if the other resource is printed or displayed?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. They had already added the option by the time I got to the survey. It's the first thing I checked!

Comment: @tripleee It's not only books. It's books / physical media - which would include magazines.

Comment: From a different perspective; I think the (lack of) selection in the school library poisoned any inclinations I ever had to go look for tech-related information from books. The library was consistently the last place I could ever find anything that was even 5 years relevant regarding any technology; that's eons in internet time lol.

Comment: Haha. How about face to face with a teacher. Remember that! [See this ...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382766/what-languages-were-used-for-coding-50-years-ago/384346#384346)

Comment: @rene yes. As in, I started with MSX 1 then graduated to MSX 2 later on.

Comment: Also back in the days when Internet barely existed, we had to read this obscure thing called "the manual".

Comment: I think the importance of books depends heavily on tech. In some technologies books are (IMO) 100% vital to getting anything done at all (C++, C, winapi/old windows APIs, Objective-C, Assembly, VB6, Verilog/VHDL, Fortran, general theory), in other techs the internet / electronic manuals / online docs have a lot of good information (.NET, Python, Ruby, Javascript, Matlab).

Comment: Does Programmer Humor on Reddit count for this?

Comment: Books? I think you’re imagining stuff, those don’t exist... :)

Comment: @Métoule Don't worry, I'm young, and I still prefer books to learn stuff over any other media. Technically, any text media could do the job, but online article tend to be shallower than books.

Answer (score 82):

Noticeably lacking this survey was a section to provide feedback on the state of Stack Overflow.

Notably included was a poll on who uses crypto.

It may not be intentional, but this survey feels a little colder than previous years. Seemingly its conclusions will have less impact, and more than likely include more hand waving.

Comment: Included when? Last year? Before that?

Comment: I didn't see any poll about who uses crypto?  I wonder if I missed part of the survey or something? @Travis J

Comment: @PeterMortensen There were several in the 2020 survey e.g. [1](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020#community-compared-to-last-year-how-welcome-do-you-feel-on-stack-overflow) , [2](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020#community-what-would-developers-change-about-stack-overflow) , [3](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020#community-relax-restrictions-on-off-topic)

Comment: Apparently these have been factored out into a separate survey. (That I just completed) But that also felt a little short...

Comment: Providing feedback on SO belongs in a different survey. Noticeably lacking was any interesting question about developer life, same as last year's.

Answer (score 78):

When did Node.js become a programming language?

[image: Survey screenshot]

As [a runtime environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), I'd call it a framework, library, or tool.

Comment: I'd call it an engine or platform, personally.

Comment: When updating the survey this year, Node.js admittedly bounced around between different sections based on the Meta post and internal discussions to find a place where it felt right, so we decided to add it into the languages section but appreciate the feedback!

Comment: @Stephanie Consider renaming "cloud platforms" to "platforms" and putting it there?

Comment: I think a new section called Compiler/Interpreters should be added. In most language, there's just one official source and most people use it but in JavaScript, where there's no official interpreter that I know of, or C where I don't know what happened to the official one. Would be quite interesting.

Comment: Also notable - Node.js and Deno are on different lists when in reality they are competing with each other. They aren't *identical* but I'd definitely expect them on the same list. Right now Node.js is a language, Deno is a tool.

Comment: I always thought Node.JS is a framework (platform) and its language is JavaScript/TypeScript, just the same way that .NET is a framework and C# is the language. Seems like this year there are more marketing guys in SO than programmers.

Answer (score 69):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Since when is [COBOL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407264/5306507) a *tool*?
[image: Survey screenshot]

I usually think of it as [a programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL).

Comment: Aren't programming languages, in fact, tools?

Comment: @CodyGray Aren't operating systems tools too? *All* the tech things in the survey could go on the tools page. Problem solved ;-)

Comment: A far more interesting question might be a modern version of _choosing between pest and cholera_: if you had to pick one, would you chose COBOL 14 or COVID 19?

Comment: Hmmm, @Cody, I didn't know I'm tooling with IDE, Wait I thought IDE is a tool, Programming language is a language.

Answer (score 58):

> If you use security or ad-blocking plugins, you may see error messages. Our third-party software provider, Qualtrics, does not work well with certain ad blockers and security software. To avoid error messages that prevent you from taking the survey, please try specifically unblocking Qualtrics in your plugin or pausing the plugin while you take the survey.

It would be great if you didn't rely on a survey system that slurps up and sells personal information and breaks when that slurping is blocked (assuming that's actually true and you're not just saying to disable it so you get revenue for personal info...). There are plenty of options for this kind of thing, some of them even open source-friendly.

Also, for what it's worth, I had no problems with 1Blocker in Safari on macOS.

Comment: I mean... Qualtrics is a data collection and market research company, data collection and analysis is *literally* what they're paid to do, so. Looks like [the only tracker on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0nIb.png) seems to be a first-party one; I had it blocked and didn't have any issues though either.

Comment: Pihole completely blocked the site for me (along with SO's qualtrics subdomain)

Comment: Is it Stack Overflow's message or is it Qualtrics'?

Comment: @BSMP SO's. Qualtrics on its own just fails to render anything if blocked.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I was wondering if the verbiage was something required or recommended by Qualtrics or if it was something Stack Overflow wrote based an issues with previous surveys.   (Though that is still useful to know.)

Comment: Something blocked this survey for me either, had no time or intent to investigate. No big loss I hope :)

Comment: Exactly my thoughts.

Comment: My company's draconian firewall blocked me from the entire survey. Oh, well...

Comment: You could, y'know, take it at home. Or on another connection.

Answer (score 57):

Survey felt... ok-ish. All in all, I personally did not find the questions interesting, and I don't think I will be rushing to see the results to look at how people answered to the classical language/framework/nationality/age/gender questions that are always there. However, this is not to say that I did not like the survey, or that the questions were bad. Those were decent questions, and the whole thing surely felt shorter and more straight to the point than last year, which I think is good. I just feel like throwing at least one funny or "different" question in there wouldn't have hurt. Sad to see that, once again, [none of the very interesting questions proposed last year was considered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393644/take-the-2020-developer-survey/393650#393650).

Comment: Same disappointment here; while it was short this year, it wasn't sweet... the things that make the survey interesting/worth doing/reading are the responses to those interesting questions... This one felt phoned in like last years...

Comment: @TylerH yeah definitely agree on that point. It just depends on what they want the SO survey to be. If they just want a "regular", uninteresting survey then they got it. If they want something fun that SO users look forward to then there's still work to do. Meh.

Answer (score 49):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Currently, 138 of the 193 United Nations (UN) member states and two non-member states have recognized Palestine. Stack Overflow's developer survey recognizes Hong Kong and Taiwan (which is recognized by fewer than 20 member states). These are far more internationally contentious.

[image: Developer Survey]

Stack Overflow should recognize the Occupied Palestinian Territory in its member survey too. This term is accepted by The United Nations, the European Union, International Committee of the Red Cross, and the government of the United Kingdom. [This is also the official name with ISO](https://web.archive.org/web/20110722001642/http://www.iso.org/iso/newsletter_v-2_palestinian_territory_occupied.pdf), before it was changed to the State of Palestine, which is also acceptable.

<sub>Note: This concern was [previously posted on Meta Stack Exchange by user157251](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364819), but that question was closed because it is an issue unique to Stack Overflow's survey. Therefore, I am reposting it here in a more appropriate forum, on behalf of those who are affected by it.</sub>

Comment: IMO the survey shouldn’t even ask where someone lives, but Palestine should be recognized.

Comment: This answer should be deleted as opinion based. Using your moderator status is not cool in this regard. There is a reason such things get closed. Another valid opinion is to exclude Taiwan and Hong Kong. Who's to decide?

Comment: @Gulzar - although I dislike political discourse, I have to chime in: exactly for this reason. This is no different than asking what gender one identifies with - if you ask, you should include all options regardless of the opinion. Same with countries: if at least *some* countries recognize a state, it should be included - who are we to decide what is a country and what isn't? If anything, the initial omission shows the bias of a certain country (and the choice of the survey provider based in the said country to play it safe).

Comment: @OlegValter I'm perfectly fine with not asking this at all, or with showing all options, or with not showing all options. I am perfectly against using moderator power to recreate deleted questions about opinion based topics. Also, Hanna's opinion is very clear - this is not about showing options on a survey. It is about screaming `the occupied Palestinian's` scream. SO is not reddit. This is not the place.

Comment: @Gulzar I do understand your point (and believe me, I agree with it in general - in my view the political statements have no business on SO). Just that I think this case is, unfortunately, political (a country not recognizing a state because of political affiliation with another), and we should be pragmatical about it: the OP got destroyed on MSE, so Hannah took it to repost here as advised in comments on the original question. Now it has "status-completed" which shows that it had merit. If you want to reduce the political overtones of the post, I think an edit should suffice, not deletion.

Comment: @Gulzar Answers don't get deleted for being "opinion based", especially on Meta sites. That aside, this answer is perfectly fine. For better or worse, the survey actually *does* ask this question, which opens up a whole bunch of politically-charged issues (i.e., geopolitics). As such, this is totally valid and relevant criticism of the survey, and stands as a feature request for how to make the survey better. You are certainly welcome to agree or disagree with the request/criticism, but you can and should indicate that (dis)agreement by *voting* on the answer, not by flagging it.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. Does the status-completed tag mean it was accepted and that the change will be reflected in next year's survey?

Answer (score 43):

I was surprised to see how inconsistent and confusing the UI for options were. There were square checkboxes that should have been radio buttons:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 41):

"Worked with in PAST year" and "Want to work with NEXT year" questions are extremely ambiguous.

If they would be taken literally, without adding any bombastic interpretations and titles, like "most loved" and "most dreaded" technologies that would probably be fine. But talking from past experience, [2019 Survey, for example](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted), those sections will probably be grossly misinterpreted.

"Worked with in PAST year" is OK-ish, but just because someone worked with technology does not mean they like it or even they know it well enough to form qualified judgement. Also "Worked" is rather broad. Should I include technology I used one week, because I had to patch something old, or should I include only technologies I used more often.

"Want to work with NEXT year" is really problematic. Should I check technologies I will most likely work with, should I check ones I would like to learn even though I would probably not have the time for them. Should I omit checking ones I worked with in past year, but I am hoping I will not have to use them in next.

Adding more check options would give better overview.

- Learned X in PAST - but never used for any real work or side project
- Worked with X in PAST (anytime)
- Learned X in PAST year
- Worked with X in PAST year
- Will work with X in NEXT year (continuation of current projects)
- Want to learn X in NEXT year
- Want to work with X in NEXT year
- Rate X - empty or 0 indicating that you don't want/cannot rate + some scale 1-10
- Expertise level in technology - 0-10

Comment: Very probably most people will work with NEXT year what they've worked with PAST year and if not they may not know yet what will change. What about: are working with CURRENTLY and would like to be working with CURRENTLY? Two absolutely unambiguous questions and the difference tells you how happy people are.

Comment: @Trilarion I rephrased it and added another option. I personally like "currently", but I think that past and next are less ambiguous. Besides that, I left rating because it still gives more gradual expression of how happy people are with some technology.

Comment: I don't see them as ambiguous at all. Either you worked with a lang or you didn't. Either you want to work with a lang in the future or you don't.

Comment: @TylerH I want to work with X because it pays my bills does not mean I like working in X or I like X. I maybe like Y, but don't want to work in Y because pay is low.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar And? It isn't asking if you like them, only if you want to work with them. It isn't much use trying to ascertain which languages are the most "loved" because what someone loves is subjective based on their own preferences. But people wanting to work with something can lead back to things like "this is a stable market/I can get a job in this" which itself is far more interesting/valuable information, to people programming as a profession anyway.

Comment: @TylerH I know, but in past those kind of questions were misinterpreted to mean like/hate https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar If they misinterpret that data I'm ready to pounce on them; I think people have shared ample criticism of misinterpretations and mischaracterizations for past survey items as well.

Comment: @TylerH Getting more accurate information is exactly why I broadened the question with additional options. Also including learners as separate category can also give more information about trends.

Comment: It might also be interesting to compare this years what did you work with last year with last years what would like to work with next year and the difference could tell about unfulfilled desires.

Comment: I deliberately reinterpreted these particular questions to fit with how SO will interpret the data. I checked boxes to indicate which languages I like and dislike (factoring in externals like library availability). I've had people tell me stuff like "You should learn Rust, devs love it more than C++, see this survey!" or "I've heard people hate VB, so let's switch to C# for new projects.". IMO SO has historically really really stretched the meaning of this question for the sake of making headlines, it's a very poor fit for "love" and "hate", as written, to be honest.

Comment: E.g., I've got a soft spot for Objective-C as a language but I wouldn't use it outside of iOS / Mac OSX, from a pure language design perspective it'd win the award for "favorite language" from me, but it doesn't have a lot of applications for me. I think C# is really great for some things on Windows. I think C++ is "OK" for all OSes, but I have yet to find a UI library I really like. The language isn't as important as what you can do with it.

Comment: Also... one other thing, this survey is self-fulfilling, I would bet that people look at which languages pay the most and say "wow I sure would like to work with those next year"

Answer (score 27):

The verbiage on the page for claiming the Census badge is unclear. I thought I could claim the badge on all the sites listed, so I clicked on one of the other sites first out of curiosity, only to find out that now I can't claim the badge on Stack Overflow.

If I had known it was one site only, I would have selected Stack Overflow. If the badge is 'earnable' on multiple sites, it should just be a network-wide badge, frankly.

Comment: We'll look into changing the wording so that others don't have this problem in the future.

Comment: @Catija shouldn’t this be marked as status review then?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica: The [status-review] tag being applied to questions actually creates a ticket for us internally. Adding a status-review "tag" inline in an answer really just sort of signals that we're looking into/considering that feedback (since it doesn't automatically do anything else) – it's not really *necessary* to add such a tag to an answer if we've already left a comment stating as much.

Comment: @V2Blast I didn't understand that, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 26):

There are a number of issues with the options for students in this survey.

### Not all students are still learning to code.

[image: screenshot of the question "Which of the following options best describes you today? Here, by "developer" we mean "someone who writes code."", with the option "I am a student who is learning to code" circled]

I *am* a student; that is my full-time profession and the source of most of my code. But I already know how to program. I suggest either removing "who is learning to code" or adding an option "I am a student who writes code for school".

### Employment for students is complicated

> Which of the following best describes your current employment status?

I can only choose one option on this question, but the options aren't mutually exclusive: for example, I know many full-time students who are employed part-time.

Comment: I have the same kind of issue but at the opposite end of things. Two answers, "I used to be a developer by profession, but no longer am" and "I code primarily as a hobby", apply to me.

Comment: Perhaps the intention is to identify Computer Science students and similar, vs. something like a history degree. Or a computing night-class. Either way, the question should be clearer.

Answer (score 25):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

I have posted this bug with more details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407913):

> In the 2021 Stack Overflow Developer Survey, I am unable to uncheck
> the option in **non-mandatory questions** once I have clicked on them. I
> can only change the option but not uncheck.
>
> Please fix this bug.

Answer (score 19):

### Update

The new layout for the tech section is much better, thanks.

---

I felt like the questions in the tech side of the survey didn't give us clear enough answers. All we can answer is yes we worked with it this year, and yes we want to work with it next year. There's no "indifferent" option, so does that mean me saying I use it this year and not choosing yes next year mean my answer is going to be assumed to mean I *don't* want to work with that language next year? This leaves our answers open to interpretation rather than letting us define how we want our answer to be interpreted. I also found the accordions throughout this section annoying.

Comment: For the technologies that I wasn't going to use at all, I just left it blank. I think that's the intended behavior, but it would have been better if there was a "Will never use" option for each one.

Comment: Most of my "don't plan to work with next year" is stuff which I accidentally had to work on during the last year, so I don't *plan* to use it, but I might still will. So that's how to interpret my answers on those ones :)

Comment: I marked some as "I want to work with this next year" not because I have any particular attachment with the technology, but rather because I don't hate it and I want to continue to be on my current project which happens to use it.

Comment: "I've worked on it last year" + "I want to work on it next year" - I like this. "I want to work on it next year" - I support this in theory but I might or might not have plans or opportunity to work on it. "I worked on it last year" - maybe it was limited work or maybe it was my last job or maybe it's also my current job, I'm just not excited to work with this. I might not even hate or dislike it. Or maybe I do. So, either I'll *stop* working with this or I will not. So, quite open to interpretation, indeed.

Comment: I just didn't select 'want to work with it next year' for a given tech unless I... wanted to work with it next year.

Answer (score 16):

The web frameworks question lists jQuery as an option:

[image: 2021 Survey web frameworks question]

but jQuery is not a framework, it is a library:

[image: Google results for jQuery, red underlines by me]

Likewise, React.js is an option, but it, too, is a library, not a framework:

[image: Google results for React.js, red underlines by me]

The question does *not* include Bootstrap, for some reason, which *is* a framework, and arguably one of the most prevalent frameworks in existence.

It's also questionable whether Svelte is a framework... I would argue that it is not, personally.

I would recommend removing/throwing out any jQuery/React(/Svelte) responses for this question, and maybe updating the survey to include Bootstrap.

Comment: We grouped together web frameworks and libraries in this instance so I will update the question itself to reflect! Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Ehhh, close enough

Comment: @Stephanie That does make the subsequent page make a little more sense... I was wondering why the follow-up page lumped libraries and frameworks together when the first was specifically referencing/alleging frameworks only!

Comment: @TylerH totally! It was a copy error on our part!

Comment: > is jQuery dead? > is jQuery better than JavaScript?

Comment: But Bootstrap is on its way out after the introduction of CSS 3(?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Is this a continuation of Kevin's joke? Or are you sincerely asking?

Answer (score 15):

Very very very minor thing in the survey: it's stylized "macOS" these days, not "MacOS".  I noticed "jQuery" was capitalized with the initial lowercase, so it's not an "all answers are capitalized" thing (unless that's the error).

Comment: On the other hand, jQuery is pretty stable, whereas MacOS / OSX / macOS changes every few years, so you can't really expect even us fanbois to always get it right.

Comment: @tripleee Yeah, I Internet search every time I want to be sure as well…

Comment: Isn't "macOS" more than stylized? Isn't it the actual spelling (***yet*** another change of name, after "Mac OS X"  and "OS X")?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think that's accurate.

Answer (score 10):

## Rename "Docker" to "Containerization"

Docker is a tool, so it's not wrong. But I think you want "Containerization" in the abstract. I intend to use containers in the next year. I do not intend to use Docker. I use [podman](https://podman.io/) and [buildah](https://buildah.io/). These are open source tools created by Red Hat to create [OCI compliant containers and images](https://opencontainers.org/). They do not require root to be built or run. They can make use of Linux Kernel user-namespaces, and they have nothing to do with the Docker daemon or company (which is Trademarked).

[image: Docker]

So what is intended to be asked here, if we'll be using the Docker implementation of containerization, or any form of containerization?

Comment: I like the idea of including containerization as a technology in the survey, but all the answers to this particular survey question are brand names/ specific variants of a given technology, so I'm not sure it belongs on this question specifically. Eg, "Git" is listed instead of "Version Control", and "Mercurial" isn't included.

Comment: @zcoop98 that's also a valid point. I guess what I should have done is not checked "Docker" I generally take people that ask if I use "docker" to mean do I use containerization. But you could say this is very much like the inclusion of yarn on this list. Actually, that's even worse. The 600 lb gorilla in the js-repo space is npm, which **isn't even listed.** So if you're using npm and not Yarn, I guess don't check it. And if you're using podman/buildah instead of Docker, don't check it either.

Comment: @user157251 sounds more of a case for adding npm than renaming Docker. With that said, I'm not sure I can honestly say I've "worked with" npm or yarn extensively. I use those a lot, sure. However, I also flip my light switch every night and that I don't count that as "working with light switches". It's something I have to do. Same with npm/yarn - I just call `install` with them and occasionally whatever script there is to do something and leave it at that. Not much more effort than flipping a light switch.

Comment: @user157251 "600 lb gorilla in the js-repo space is npm, which isn't even listed" - yes! I can't agree more. NPM was also suggested for inclusion and well-received by the community (which obviously uses it and similar ones daily). Completely ignored - Yarn for some reason is in the list, but god forbid other managers making it to the list... Not to mention the mysterious "Puppet" technology (which I suppose is "Puppeteer" in reality, but here we are).

Comment: @VLAZ - well, yeah, but there is also a matter of publishing packages for the respective registry, which is far from flipping a switch in terms of effort sometimes :) Just an off-note, overall, I am very saddened that the timely suggestions to fix the questionable choices / lack of options were, as is customary, simply ignored.

Comment: @OlegValter definitely publishing and other stuff is more substantial. I'm saying that *my usage* has been a lot in volume but not very meaningful. I'm not sure whether the question wants me to tick the usage box or not for that. For the record, I ticked it. Also, I just realised that Deno is listed under tools but Node.js is with the programming languages. At the very least, both should have been in the same list.

Comment: @VLAZ sorry if this came off as an attempt to rebut your comment - I understand that you described your usage, that was more of an off-note for passer-by readers. Re: Deno/Node.js - yeah, apart from Adam's answer, I think it was also brought up several times during the suggestion period and also ignored (and as the response under the new answer is, sadly, a sugar-coated "deal with it").

Comment: @OlegValter Puppet is a very popular server provisioning platform, like Ansible that's also on the list. https://puppet.com/

Comment: @user157251 - finally, someone clarified what this is, thank you :) It's even more saddening because now I see that the list contains at least 3 infrastructure tools but couldn't be bothered with other inclusions. I am being harsher in tone than usual because I am really disappointed by the survey...

Comment: @OlegValter I assume this was funded by Puppet and Docker so they specifically could make value-statements like 50% of applicants want to use Puppet and Docker in the next year! Not sure, it does seem suspect for them to exclude other technology in the domain and to not explicitly disclaim the intent of the question. I'm cool with Docker sponsoring it (if so). But just to be clear, I checked it and don't use Docker. So it's not going to be meaningful if they're doing it to get honest data.

Comment: @ISupportTheBoycott - huh, I finally found out the reason why Puppet made it to the survey (alongside others given that it's not the only one of the category) - it was so simple, silly of me not to notice: SE has it [its tech stack](https://github.com/StackExchange?q=&type=&language=puppet&sort=). That's how it made it.

Answer (score 10):

> "As happened in previous years, any user who completes the survey in its entirety will earn the Census badge. You will have the option to get the badge on Stack Overflow, or on a different **technical** site in the Stack Exchange network.".

Could the list of sites where the Census badge is awarded be expanded to include a few more sites?

While the survey text claims that the badge is only offered for "technical" sites it is in fact offered for "science" sites too. There are some technical and science sites, where awarding the badge to "programmers", (if that is the limit of this particular survey), that are missing from the list of choices offered at the end of the survey.

I checked the [historical posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bsurvey%5d%20is%3aquestion) for surveys. It seems that initially the badge was only offered on Stack Overflow, later the list of sites was expanded; but there doesn't seem to be any discussion or mention of how the list was chosen. It seems like some sites are missing out; that ought to be included.

- It [may](https://devops.stackexchange.com/tags/jenkins/info) or [may not](https://devops.stackexchange.com/tour) be appropriate for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/tags/), and somewhere like [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) perhaps less so; though that site was included.
- Similarly, we have [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where programming questions are off-topic, (even though we don't have [Internet of Things](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/a/357/9412)).
- No [Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (Lisp).
- No [ExpressionEngine](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [SiteCore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/tour), or [Tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (even though we have [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) also a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)).

Those choices and exceptions make it challenging to figure out where the line is drawn, and which sites one could ask to be included on the list. I'm left to suggest sites that allow programming questions but seem to have missed out being included, perhaps since some are new.

I'm not sure beta status should be a consideration, as there are many other unique badges awarded on those sites, even a few graduated sites are missing out.

Some suggested additions where the Census badge should also be able to be awarded:

- **[Technology](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-name):**

  - [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  - [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  - [Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  - [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  - [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tour)
  - [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/help/on-topic)
- **[Science](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science-name):**

  - [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  - [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  - [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  - [Economics](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1913/21815)
  - [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/51/10320)
  - [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157/making-the-software-tag-work-for-you)
  - [Operations Research](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  - [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- **[Professional](https://stackexchange.com/sites#professional-name):**

  - [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315/what-questions-can-be-asked-at-cseducators)

---

**Additional References:**

List of sites where Census badge can be awarded, as indicated by the Survey text:

> [image: List of sites where Census badge can be awarded]

List of "[Technology](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-name)" sites:

> [image: List of "Technology" sites]

List of "[Science](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science-name)" sites:

[image: List of "Science" sites]

Answer (score 9):

> Approximately how many people are employed by the company or organization you currently work for?

I work for a company with over 20,000 employees worldwide and a few thousand in the UK but only a small portion are any sort of software developer. Maybe future surveys should examine company size versus division size versus number of software (or IT) people.

> What is your current total compensation (salary, bonuses, and perks, before taxes and deductions), ...

I choose to work part time, my contract is for 3 days per week. So I receive approximately 3/5 of the compensation given for full time work. Should I have given my compensation or the equivalent if scaled up to a full week? We have a few other people with similar contracts. I imagine that most people viewing the survey are interested in the compensation packages that full time workers get. If I and a few others put in our actual, but reduced, numbers then I wonder whether that will that distort the survey results.

Comment: I presumed the intent was something akin to "total pre-tax pay", so regardless of situation, it was asking for the hourly/ weekly/ monthly/ yearly total, whichever was most convenient to give. No scaling necessarily required.

Comment: @zcoop98 Think about the purpose of the question. Is it about understanding the range of compensation packages enjoyed by full time employees? Can it be useful to compare (or combine) the numbers for part time workers against (with) those of full time workers?

Comment: Respectfully, I still don't think it matters; you're working part time, and bringing home *X* dollars. Both of those are true statements. Whether that dollar amount is a function of the company's full-time salary or whether it changes based on the moon phase doesn't invalidate it being your actual compensation as a part-time employee, so I'm not sure why it would need to be recorded any differently in the survey data.

Comment: It sounds more like you're in a special employment situation that may not necessarily fit either full *or* part time, which is fully valid; I don't at all mean to dispute or argue against that lol. It could very well be useful to have a category that covers edge cases.

Comment: The employee number question also confused me. My super-mega-parent company is *huge*. It's also almost entirely unrelated to me. My parent company is quite big but also mostly irrelevant other than the name on my contract. The branch I work for (which actually does software stuff) is in the order where I could know everybody's names. But there are 2-3 offices (depends a bit) in different countries. Then the actual people I actually consider I work with are definitely split in two offices and there are maybe 50-ish of them. So, what do I actually choose there?

Comment: @zcoop98 Nothing special about my employment situation. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I think two questions would be more useful: compensation for 100% pay and hours/percentage worked. In Germany, it's relatively common for people to work a %, but contracts are worked out in terms of full-time employment. Pay of two employees would be compared at their full-time rate, even if one works 50%.

Comment: And I'm surprised furlough didn't make it into the survey.

Answer (score 8):

I just want point out more problems with the "Worked with past year" and "Will work next year" bit.

The main problem is the translation of "Will use next year" and "Worked with past" year directly to "Most dreaded" and "Most loved".

### Problem 1:

I may ***LOVE*** C but let's say I'm bored and want to experience some concurrency. So, I will not select C for "Will use next year" and instead select Go. In the results, it will falsely mean I hate C. Which will be incorrect. People may just switch for fun, that doesn't mean it's dreaded...

### Problem 2:

What if you have a job and the company is  switching languages? You still love your former language but will use another one next year.

It may be said that it is to reflect upon the popularity of the language as when the company switches, the people too switch and it become slightly less popular. Which is fine, but again the topic in the result is misleading. Dreadfullness or lovingness is not the same as popularity.

### Problem 3:

People may falsely think that they only need to select technologies that they will  use next year that they aren't already using. I almost did that but then realized otherwise. For eg. I'm using Java, I will be using Scala next year but I don't think I need to reselect Java in the "Will work with next year" section.

### Solution

1. Used last year but will stop using forever or for the near future.
2. Used last year and will continue using.
3. Didn't use last year but will start using.

Comment: The question isn't asking whether you like/love a language, only whether you want to use it next year. If you conflate the question with one asking whether you like/love a language, that's on you :-)

Comment: @TylerH Exactly! You got my point. But then in the results, they rank the languages as "Most loved" and "Most dreaded". Just changing the title in the results will fix most issues.

Comment: You have already seen the results of this year's survey?

Comment: @TylerH If they change it this year, it's absolutely fine.

Answer (score 7):

I'm just surprised how I even was not considered to be worthy of taking the survey. It's been this error page:

[image: "Access Denied: You don't have permission to access on this server."]

every single time I have tried it out.

Yes, I know I could have used a VPN to pretend I'm in New York or Washington DC, but I'm really tired of doing so. Half of my Internet budget is nastily consumed by VPNs that allow me to become a real-world citizen when I'm looking for knowledge or resources, and I'm really tired of doing so. Since nobody asked me where I would like to be born just before I was born, nobody has the right to forbid me to live or discriminate against me for living where I do.

I think this is a site about technology and knowledge—not politics—so, if I am permitted to be here, why should I not be allowed to take your surveys? Yes, I know it is due to the survey services that you hired, but you should look at a worldwide one with no such restrictions.

In the end, we all are just developers, and our personal, religious, and political beliefs should be out of the discussion, just as it is for gender or race.

Comment: Here is another user with the same / similar issue: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408259/578411

Comment: Um... I seriously doubt that SO has anything against you *in particular*... But they should definitely look into it...

Comment: quick question: can you tell if that access denied page is from qualtrics.com or does your country also have a common firewall for all traffic and are they responsible for blocking?

Comment: Also happened in the 2019 survey: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379314/578411

Comment: My country has no firewall at all. We are banished from a lot of sites just because the world's more powerful country says we support terrorism. I know it's not a personal issue but if you look into it closely you'll probably notice I was talking about my country not about me.

Comment: Okay, it is unfortunate that it has to be this way. I don't understand why Stack Overflow has no problem serving and accepting contributions from you on their site while qualiterics.com refuse to accept that. it is not that you are trying to do business with qualtrics, you are only asked to take a survey that is created by someone else. Weird politics. We appreciate you being here. Even without the survey we've plenty of things here on meta to vote on or topics your constructive input is welcome.

Comment: In other words: don't consider the survey as the only means to participate beyond what you do on the main site.

Comment: I know that. I was just pointing it out. Not worried or disgusted by the survey stuff, just using my right of speech to say that things like this would not be happening in a site like this. Just that.

Comment: I love this answer. It is well written, and it presents a real, legitimate concern in a very engaging and passionate way. You have my sincerest seal of approval. Thank you so much for posting this, even if it gets ignored by the staff who actually have the power to fix this.

Comment: Not that it solves the issue but: *As in previous years, Qualtrics blocks certain countries from accessing their site and data: Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Syria, and the Crimea region of Ukraine (including Sevastopol). In addition, some users in China may have issues due to restrictions imposed by local internet service providers. This is unfortunate, and we can do nothing about it. We’ve continued to research alternatives, but so far have found no alternative that provides a cost effective alternative, considering the work we’ve already put in to configure Qualtrics.*

Comment: Second to last paragraph in the blog announcement: https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/05/25/the-2021-developer-survey-is-now-open/

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I have just read the blog announcement after your comment.

Comment: Would it be horrible to consider using Google Forms? AFAIK that is available worldwide.

Comment: There are many horrible things that we are forced to do everyday, what would it be so horrible about taking Google Forms?

Answer (score 2):

I found there is a lot of ambiguity with the two questions:

> Which of the following describe you, if any? Please check all that apply.

They both have a "or in your own words" option but no proper indication of what is appropiate. For example, should dyslexia/other learning difficulties be mentioned  along with ADHD, depression, and autism? Or are those out of scope and not what your looking for?

Comment: A list of the existing options would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the link to the survey shows a notice that the survey is closed, but it references the 2019 survey.

[image]

I know it's not a big issue but it might be worth adding this to a list of things to correct for next year's survey.  Also, it might be nice to have a link to the survey results in that message.

Answer (score 0):

#### This has to be a check box right?!

[image: The question, "Which of the following options best describes you today?" followed by six answers with radio buttons to choose one.]

Comment: No, it's asking you to pick the one that ***best* describes you today**. There can only be one "best". Therefore, it's an option/radio button to indicate an exclusive (not multiple) choice.

Comment: Got it, Makes sense.

Answer (score -4):

This did feel like a much better survey than other years. Shorter, better choices and nicely implemented. Of course, it had the same issue it always has: it was assuming that anyone who codes will be an avid SO user, forgetting that there is a lot of coding expertise, especially with scripting languages like perl, python, awk, or even the shell, on the various other technical sites.

I completely understand that the vast majority of coders are most active on SO, and I get that you are primarily interested in SO users (fair enough, they're ~100 times the size of any other SE community) but it just feels weird for me to say "I participate in Q&A once a month or less" while I practically live on the SE network. I just fear you're getting slightly misleading data from people like me who do code for a living, albeit not as their primary role, but spend most of their time on SE on non-SO sites.

Comment: I haven't taken the survey yet.  Does the question you're objecting too explicitly limit its scope to Q&A on Stackoverflow vs Stack Exchange as a whole?

Comment: I am very happy that you liked the survey this year and we really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight it is more than one question, and I'm not objecting as such. I can understand if SE only really care about the SO user's for a developer survey, I was just pointing it out. Unfortunately, they use the ambiguous term "SO" which for some people means this site, for others the network, for others the company. So I don't know what is meant but for me, "SO" means this site only.

Answer (score -4):

First-time survey taker here. I'd drop the parts about what genitalia one has/identifies as having and what they like to do with it. It just seems vulgar, absurd, and not at all relevant. Not to mention that it takes up space that could have been used for feedback on issues relevant to the field that was the entire purpose of my taking the survey, to begin with. -1.

Comment: This is the first time you've ever taken a survey that asked for demographic information about its respondents? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: They're all 100% skippable, you don't even need to choose prefer not to answer.

Comment: @CodyGray sorry, i could have been clearer. it was my first SO survey. and, as im not an avid survey taker, my fist time in any survey being asked if i was a trans-what-have-you.

Comment: @KevinB them being optional doesnt really make it any less vulgar/absurd/irrelevant. i took the survey to offer my small voice on the issues i see with the SO community so that i might help make it better. however, i wasnt offered an opportunity to do that. but i WAS offered an opportunity to express my perceived genitalia and what i like to do with it. vulgar, absurd and irrelevant.

Comment: I don't disagree that it's useless information, however I disagree with it being in any way vulgar

Comment: @KevinB put it down to cultural differences i suppose. where i come from, those sorts of topics are considered largely private in most formal settings.

Comment: Perhaps you are missing my point. While I agree that this information is largely irrelevant and probably shouldn't be collected, it is commonly collected in *all* surveys, grouped into a category called "demographic information". It includes things like your gender, your age, your income level, and a bunch of other stuff that one might rightly consider to be private (aka none of your business). This is not in any way unique to Stack Overflow or its survey.