# What is "Worked With vs. Want to Work With" and "Most loved, dreaded, and wanted" in the Developer Survey results?

Tags: discussion, survey-2021

In 2021 we introduced a new section to the Technology chapter of our annual Developer Survey results. We titled this section **Worked With vs. Want to Work With**. Our hope with this section is to expand on the popular **Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted** section (first introduced in [2015](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2015#tech-super)) by showing precisely what developers used in the past year and what they want to work with in the following year at a granular level.

This post aims to clearly explain **Worked With vs. Want to Work With** and how to interpret the visualization we chose. It can also explain the intuition behind "Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted" if this is your first time reading our survey results.

### Refresher on "Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted"

Before jumping into how to interpret the visualization let's have a quick refresher on how we structure our survey and what in the world Love, Dread, and Want mean.

[image: Screenshot of "worked with in past year"/ "want to work with next year" survey section, and colored markup indicating that lines with only a "past year" selection are categorized as "Dreaded", lines with just "next year" selected are "Wanted", and lines with both selected are "Loved"]

Above we are looking at the database question. You can see that there are multiple databases listed and the survey respondent can choose what databases that they *have* worked with and the ones they *want* to work with.

We defined the categories as follows:

- **Loved** (MySQL) = *Worked with in PAST year* **AND** *Want to work with NEXT year*
- **Dreaded** (MariaDB) = *Worked with in PAST year* **BUT** **DO NOT** *Want to work with NEXT year*
- **Wanted** (Redis) = **DID NOT** *Worked with in PAST year* **BUT** *Want to work with NEXT year*

These three metrics have become an integral part of our developer survey in recent years. And rightfully so as they are able to take our quantitative results and share them in a way that developers and non-developers can connect to.

### Why

In the above example, you can see that Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted can only describe a single database.  But we can plainly see that this respondent wants to move away from MariaDB, continue using MySQL, and start using Redis.

### Introducing **Worked With vs. Want to Work With**

This *"from and to"* path is exactly what we wanted to show in this year's survey. To visualize this path we chose to use a [Chord Diagram](https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/chord.html). While chord diagrams can look intimidating (they were for me) at first glance they can offer lots of insights if interpreted correctly. Especially if they are interactive which was a must-have if we wanted to use them.

#### Single From and To Path

When highlighting a single path we can see it's *from* and *to* databases. Here we see that 5,120 respondents worked with MariaDB this year but wanted to work with MySQL next year.

[image: Chord diagram with the arc from MariaDB to MySQL highlighted]

#### All Paths

When hovering over a single database we can see all the paths that connect to it. It looks like MySQL has paths moving to every other database with the exception of Microsoft SQL Server. When looking at the different colored paths we can see that only four databases are leading *to* it (MariaDB, MongoDB, PostgresSQL, SQLite):

[image: Chord diagram with all paths to/ from MySQL highlighted]

#### Self Connecting Paths

If a path is from and to the same database then this is the equivalent of **Loved** because these developers are currently working in MySQL and want to continue working in MySQL:

[image: Chord diagram with the self-referential arc on MySQL highlighted]

### FAQ

- Why aren't all options visualized?

  - We set a minimum number of responses an option must have in order to be visualized. If we included every path the visualization would be extremely hard to interpret.
- Why not use a [parallel plot](https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/parallel.html)?

  - We considered it but were unable to get the results we wanted with the categorical data that we have.

Comment: I believe these stats have been misinterpreted. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407941 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407926 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407943

Comment: So just confirmation that if we answered this survey with the intent of showing what we worked with, but didn't mark it as also a want, it's going to be assumed we hate that tool/language (rather than giving us the ability to actually indicate that)

Comment: @KevinB, We are only assuming that if you told us that you worked with a tool/language but do not want to work with it next year, you “dread” using that tool/language. It would be a lot to assume that you hate that tool/language, but since you told us for whatever reason you do not want to work with that tool, then we can assume it is dreaded for one reason or another.

Comment: I've worked with Java in the past year. I *don't mind* working with Java the next year. I'm *OK* with Java. I not selected that I *want* to work with Java because I'm more interested in other technologies and I feel like I have enough years with Java under my belt that I can expand my horizons without focusing on Java.

Comment: You're reading a lot into a couple of yes/no questions. Someone might have worked with a technology they liked, but do not want to work with it next year for implications that can have for one's career (e.g., stuck in the same job vs getting transferred or promoted to a position with different needs).

Comment: If you want to know what people "Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted", *please just ask that*.

Comment: I can ask a separate question if needed, but can someone please explain how this works? Why is it that VS Code being loved by 46k users is somehow *less* than Neovim being loved by only 3k users? How is that graphic useful at all? And many other similar situations

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is just a really misinterpreted "results". Not only have you exaggerated the response you got on the survey, but you've invented meaning behind the responses. It's click-batey, but consider how you're shaping the future with this. Some may think there's a shred of truth being those terms you're using. How about this scenario: I worked with MariaDB the past year, but I don't want to work with it the next year, because at my company, the project that uses it is located 120 miles from my home. I want to work with MySQL because in that team they have "Happy hour" every friday.

Comment: Oh whoops, I misread that completely. I interpreted as "not using yet but ALSO want to use". I don't much believe in starting to dread and removing tools from your toolbelt, you want to add more to it and maybe use existing tools less.

Comment: Perhaps add a reference to the [corresponding podcast episode](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/03/podcast-363-highlights-from-our-2021-developer-survey/) ([MP3](https://cdn.simplecast.com/audio/6fa1d34c-502b-4abf-bd82-483804006e0b/episodes/80e434b4-2a54-4a92-81f4-8c0f5514cbbf/audio/beb9cb30-feb1-484e-8d6e-47adba455875/default_tc.mp3)) to this question - with the *exact* timestamp?

Comment: Bad question will get you bad results. Also you need to normalize the data. I looked at the csv for 2020 and there are a lot of questionable numbers, like I seriously doubt that someone was earning more than a million per year or less than 40,000. 
For next year you should ask:
1. Worked in last year
2. Will work in next year
3. Want to learn next year
4. Refuse to work with
5. Lang I recommend
6. Lang I do NOT recommend

Answer (score 28):

Making wide statements like "loved", "dreaded", or even "wanted" based on a couple of checkboxes that aren't labeled as such are just assumptions that can't be supported.

If I had taken this survey, I would have marked ElasticSearch as "Worked With" and not "Want to Work With". That doesn't mean I hate it. It just means I'm ambivalent about it. I needed it for work for one project, but I don't see myself using it again any time soon.

If Python had been on the survey, I'd have left both checks unmarked and I absolutely hate that language. I tried to learn it a couple of years ago and the tutorial thought it would be a good idea to use a bug as an example of how the white space is such a "great thing" and that you need "steely eyed missile man" sight in order to work with it. So me not marking the checks means I won't use it, not dread it, which is contrary to current the assumptions made.

If C#, Java, HTML, or a dozen other languages I use on a regular basis would have shown up on the list, I would have checked both boxes. They wouldn't show that I love the languages, though, just that I find them useful. It wouldn't even show that I'm making a career using the languages. Some of them, yes, I use professionally, but some I (also) use for personal projects and have done so for over a decade.

And if Angular, Vue, Bootstrap, or half a dozen other languages/frameworks were on the list, I'd have marked them as "Want to Work With", but that doesn't mean it'll happen. Because there's less of an assumption here, "Wanted" is the most accurate assumption, but it's still not a very good one. I want to learn those because many jobs require them, not because I really want to learn them for myself. I could just as easily "eeny, meeny, miny, moe" which one to learn first (or at all), and it wouldn't make a difference to me. So the assumption that it's my personal preference of "Wanted" still makes that label inaccurate.

Each and every person has their own list of languages they hate, use, on-the-fence, like, love, and are ambivalent/meh about. I just used some of my own examples to show how wrong this survey's assumptions are, and I didn't even fill it out.

If you really wanted to learn the details of "Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted", you should just straight out ask those questions, as MisterMiyagi and other commenters said or implied. And if you wanted to know if it was personal or business/career preference, you should specifically ask that, too. Making assumptions based on company policy/biases is part of the reason why Stack Exchange has had so many problems in the past 2-3 years.

Answer (score 14):

> Dreaded (MariaDB) = Worked with in PAST year BUT DO NOT Want to work with NEXT year

Please reconsider using "dread" to describe technologies one worked with last year but does not want to work with this year. Not wanting to work with a certain technology simply means not looking forward to working with it for a variety of reasons (which may not even be related to the technology's shortcomings).

Whereas "dread" implies a sense of fear, of being scarred for the rest of your life by the experience. Take a look at what dictionaries have to say about the word. This is the definition of "dread" from the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dread):

> to feel extremely worried or frightened about something that is going to happen or that might happen

And these are two definitions of it from the [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dread):

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 8. greatly feared; frightful; terrible
> 9. held in awe or reverential fear

And this one is from the [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dread_1):

> to feel very worried about something that might happen or something that is going to happen

It's certainly not what I (and many others) mean when they say they "don't want to work" with something. Not everything has to be a binary choice - by reducing "not want to" to "dread", you risk grossly misrepresenting how people feel about technologies as well as what significance (if any) those have for the programmer community at large.

An additional concern is that such an interpretation has a high potential of confusing people for whom English is a second language who generally rely on *common* definitions of the words.

Comment: Would you prefer detest :p

Comment: @Nick "detest" opens another can of worms :) I can come to dislike a particular technology but not detest it in the slightest (same with people) - admittedly, it would be a bit less confusing, but largely suffer from the same "do not want !== hate" issue

Comment: By that logic, you should also be complaining about Love[d], working with a tech and wanting to continue doesn't imply that large an enjoyment of it, just a wanting to continue, maybe it wasn't at all enjoyable, but you're interested in continuing to learn it for example. My point is, they're just labels, does it really matter what they are (as long as they're clear, which IMO they are)?

Comment: Well, aren't all words just that - labels? They don't have any meaning until we assign one to them by general agreement. It is my firm belief that when one does surveys on a scale of SE, it should not put conclusions like "the most dreaded language is X" lightly. To be honest, I have a similar complaint about "loved" as well, but that's out of the scope of the answer.

Comment: @Nick They're just labels that many people are going to read *without looking at the data or meaning*. "30% of people dreaded working with X" is a pretty devastating statement – and there are a lot of these to find in the survey "results".