# SO survey keyboard navigation

Tags: bug, survey, accessibility, survey-2022

I am on the page *How did you learn to code? Select all that apply.* in the 2022 Stack Overflow Developer survey. The page uses custom "checkbox" form elements and visually hidden inputs. That will probably work fine for screen readers (though I did not test), however there isn’t any *focus* indicator for keyboard navigation, at least in Firefox 100.0 on Mac OS, and it's very hard to fill the form without a mouse:

[image: Screenshot of page]

I didn't see any feedback button inside the survey. Is this the right place to report the issue? If there is a better place, please answer with a link where to report issues with the survey, thanks!

Comment: Well, you have the "*[Take the 2022 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417991/)*" Announcement/Thread where People also report Bugs/Feedback...